# Chemistry of making glass

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solutions

> To boil glass, the lime and sand mixture of potash was heated and the off gas spent $\pu{125 mL}$ of barley hydroxide solution (density $\pu{1.14 g mL-1}$). The mass of the sediment was $\pu{4.925 g}$. It is known that the ratio of gas to alkalinity is $1 : 1$.
>
> 1. Find the volume of absorbed gas.
> 2. Find mass of sodium hydroxide in solution.

This is a homework, I read the book a few times but didn't understand how to solve this. Can you please help me?

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you have any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help). Please don't use [tag:homework] tag in the future.

Comment: This is a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/7448) question. We have a policy which states that ‎you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the problem. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this question may get closed.‎ Please [edit] in your full reasoning or thoughts on this. Best of luck and welcome to Chemistry.SE.

Comment: "*...didn't understand how to solve this*" Surely you must've been taught *something* in this regard to go about solving this problem, otherwise your teacher wouldn't hand it to you. What exactly is it that you don't understand?

Comment: The question is inconsistent! What is **barley** hydroxide? Is this supposed to mean **barium** hydroxide? In the context of the question and the compounds involved, this would make sense! If so, why is then asked for the remaining **sodium** hydroxide?

Answer (score 1):

1. Apparently, a gas is released in the process of making glass. Can you figure out what that gas might be?
2. When let into an aqueous solution of a hydroxide (most likely barium), a precipitate is formed. This could give you some further intel on the nature of the gas.
3. If you know which gas was formed, you can come up with the nature of the precipitate.
4. From the molar mass of the precipitate and the given weight, you can calculate the number of moles.
5. You were given the volume and the density of the hydroxide solution. A part of the hydroxide has reacted to yield the precipitate. You should now be able to calculate how much is left in solution.